# how to always ensure a 1D signal is the preferred way up (orientation)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 1D signals coming as such as these...

[image]

[image]

I am looking for a way to always orient them like the bottom signal (mountains rather than valleys) at all times.

This is an example array I converted to int for space.

```py
sig = np.array([39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 40, 40, 40, 39, 40, 40, 36, 30, 23, 15,
        8,  3,  0,  0,  3, 10, 17, 26, 32, 36, 38, 38, 38, 39, 38, 39, 39,
       39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 38, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39,
       39, 38, 39, 39, 40, 38, 35, 28, 21, 14,  8,  3,  0,  0,  4, 10, 18,
       27, 33, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 38, 38, 40, 39, 39, 38, 38, 39, 39,
       39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 38, 34,
       29, 22, 14,  8,  3,  0,  0,  4, 10, 19, 27, 33, 36, 39, 39, 40, 39,
       40, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40, 40, 39, 40, 40, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39,
       39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 35, 27, 20, 13,  7,  2,  0,  0,
        5, 12, 20, 29, 35, 37, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 40,
       40, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39,
       39, 38, 33, 27, 20, 12,  6,  2,  0,  1,  6, 14, 22, 31, 36, 38, 38,
       38, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 38, 39, 40, 39, 40, 40, 40, 39, 40, 40, 39,
       40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 36, 31, 25, 17, 10,  4,
        0,  0,  2,  8, 16, 24, 31, 35, 37, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 38,
       40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 40,
       40, 39, 39, 40, 36, 30, 24, 16,  9,  4,  0,  0,  3,  9, 17, 26, 32,
       36, 38, 39, 39, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40, 40, 40, 38, 40, 39, 40, 39, 40,
       39, 40, 40, 38, 40, 40, 39, 40, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 38, 34, 28, 20,
       14,  8,  3,  0,  0,  5, 11, 20, 28, 34, 37, 39, 38, 38, 39, 38, 39,
       39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 38, 40, 39, 39, 40, 39, 38, 39, 39, 38, 38,
       39, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 35, 31, 24, 17, 10,  4,  1,  0,  1,  7, 15,
       22, 30, 35, 37, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 38, 39, 39, 38, 38, 39, 38, 39,
       38, 39, 39, 38, 38, 40, 39, 38, 39, 38, 38, 38, 39, 38, 38, 38, 35,
       28, 21, 13,  7,  2,  0,  0,  3, 10, 19, 27, 33, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38,
       38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 40, 38, 39, 38,
       38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 38, 38, 39, 36, 31, 25, 17, 10,  4,  1,  0,  1,
        7, 14, 22, 29, 34, 36, 38, 37, 38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 38, 38, 37, 38,
       37, 39, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 38, 38, 37, 38, 37])
```

**Update**

One function that seems to work well via @Mr.T is:

```
def orient_sig(sig):
    mn = np.min(sig)
    mx = np.max(sig)
    
    half = 0.5*(mn+mx)
    above = sig > half
    below = sig <= half
    nabove = above.sum()
    nbelow = below.sum()
    if nabove > nbelow:
        sig = np.max(sig) - sig
    return sig
```

`fixed_sig = np.apply_along_axis(orient_sig, 0, sig)`

One spanner in the works is that the signal can drift in rare cases...

[image]

The initial solution by @mozway is great, though if there is another way here for this edge case, do let me know.

Comment: Check whether more points are above or below 0.5*(min+max)?

Comment: Wouldnt you ruin the signal data then? Bc you are flipping it, and therefore reversing the data itself?

Comment: @Griff can you provide a sample dataset?

Comment: @Mr.T that is a great suggestion. And to answer the other question, it doesn't ruin the data because it's meant to be all like the bottom and the only reason I am getting data like to the top is because of an imaging orientation aspect of the how the signals are generated.

Comment: @mozway I updated it with upside down array.

Comment: @Griff can you provide the drifting baseline sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the mean is above the median, and use a trick of 2*boolean-1 to map True/False to 1/-1 to swap the sign:

```
def orient_up(sig):
    return (2*(sig.mean()>np.median(sig))-1) * sig

plt.plot(orient_up(sig))
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you mozway, much appreciated - can you see any edge cases where this might not work? Is it also better than my function of looking at 0.5*(min+max).

Comment: I think it is better than `0.5*(min+max)` (which was also my initial thinking) as that would rely on only 2 points, so would be sensible to outliers. In contrast, mean/median are robust descriptors. Given the density of your data I expect it to work fine. You could also use quartiles, something like `0.5*(Q(0.1)+Q(0.9))`

Comment: Yeh thanks. I just added an edge case where some signals drift up sometimes, would you have any ideas as to how to deal with those as well?

Comment: Yes probably, can you provide samples?

Comment: I'll see how I go with the one you provided and then find a good example of where it might not work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Griff can you provide the green curve anyway? this is a fun thing to do ;)